# Get count of unique year repeated throughout the event by groupby pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Below is my data.

```
CompanyEvents   StartDate:year
Event1              2013
Event1              2013
Event1              2013
Event1              2014
Event1              2015
Event2              2013
Event2              2013
Event2              2015
Event3              2011
```

I want output like :

```
CompanyEvents   Year    Unique Year Count
Event1      2013    3
Event1      2013    3
Event1      2013    3
Event1      2014    3
Event1      2015    3
Event2      2013    2
Event2      2013    2
Event2      2015    2
Event3      2011    1
```

Event1 is repeating in three unique years 2013,2014,2015 so count is 3.
Event2 is also repeating in two unique years 2013,2015 so count is 2.
same with event3.

Comment: do you have to do it in pandas? It is quite easy to achieve that in regular python code.

Comment: Yes as I have to do it using groupby. Also data is huge, just for example I have given this dummy data.